# Convert.ToDateTime() not working on Server.. Give format exception

Tags: c#, datetime

```
TxtPolCreatedDate.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(TxtPolCreatedDate.Text).ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy");
```

Its working fine on local machine but not working on server . I have also checked for the `Date.Parse()` and specify culture as suggested on

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9xk1h71t(v=vs.110).aspx.

But not working..

Comment: Does your local machine and server have different cultures? What is the exception?

Comment: Have you encountered `Input string was not in current format`? Put breakpoint on the line and check if `TxtPolCreatedDate.Text` property has proper `DateTime` format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot for your response.. But this is not working in my case.
I got solution.. If we add

```
[<globalization uiCulture="en" culture="en-GB" enableClientBasedCulture="true "/>]
```

in web.config file . then it will not give format exception..

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(TxtPolCreatedDate.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Because `Convert.ToDateTime` uses the current culture of the server and probably the server's current culture's `DateTime` format is different from yours. So the solution is using `ParseExact` method and pass the culture explicitly.

**Reference** : [DateTime.ParseExact Method (String, String, IFormatProvider)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)